# Code after If statement always running even if condition returns false?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have an If statement looking at the result of a Test-Path command. The code after the If statement always seems to run, however, even when the test-Path returns False (I have proved this by piping the result of test-Path to a Write-Host command). What am I missing? Code here:

```
If (Test-Path  "\\server\students\home\$user") { 
            $user = $_.uname 
            Set-ItemProperty -Path "\\server\students\home\$user" -Name Attributes -Value "Normal"
            $acl = Get-Acl "\\server\students\home\$user"
            $acl.access | where-object {$_.AccessControlType -eq "Deny"} | Foreach-object { $acl.RemoveAccessRule($_) }
            (Get-Item "\\server\students\home\$user").SetAccessControl($acl)
            Get-ChildItem -Path "\\swcportal\students\home\$user\*" -Recurse | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse
            Remove-Item "\\server\students\home\$user" -Recurse
            Write-host "$user's home directory deleted successfully"
            }
```

Comment: Are you sure that you don't mean to use `$_.uname` in the `IF`. You are using `$user` in the `IF` but then using a different value straight-away.

Comment: If this code is in a loop, then you might be using the value from a previous TRUE result by having $user in the IF test.

Comment: As previously stated by @DeanOC you are using `$User` in the `Test-Path`, if `$User` has no value your IF will be testing the path of \\server\students\home\ which i'm thinking is always coming up as `True`.

You can try enclosing your first IF in a second IF like `If ($user)` which will only run if `$User` is set to something.